# Add static value between second & third menu value

Tags: wordpress, menu

How can I add a static value between second and third menu value?

For example, like this:

Menu value 1, Menu value 2, STATIC VALUE HERE, Menu value 3, Menu value 4

I know about the Walker_Nav_Menu and start_el/end_el. But this adds prefix to all menu values. I just want to add one - as stated - in between second and third value.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery append() and html() set unique classes to each menu item in WordPress' menu builder, then use the 3rd menu item's class as the selector for append and put whatever static HTML you want on the end of that menu item.

Answer (score 0):

Add a "dummy" element to the menu in the WordPress admin panel (add a "link" whose href is `#` or something) where you want your "static value" (whatever you mean by that).  This will create the additional `li` in the place you need.

Once you've done that, the easiest way to modify it is to use jQuery (or plain JS).  Target the li in question with with a jQuery selector string and use `html()`, `prepend()` or `append()` jQuery methods to modify the li or add stuff to it as needed.  Otherwise you'll need to dig into some pretty serious PHP to modify the `wp_nav_menu()` function, or alternately replace your WP3 menu with a static one that's part of the template rather than generated through the backend.